# Copy the output of a task to file and store it in azure artifacts in Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I Just deployed Kubeadvisor and I got the output as below. I want to store this output as a file in azure artifacts. Need suggestions please

Comment: I dont see any output attached, Can you attach yaml file or any supporting material?

Comment: Hi Baba, any update on this issue,  just as Rezwan mentioned, we do not see any output attached. If issue still persist, please provide more detail info for analysis.